# Difference between rename! and rename with new DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, rename, julia

Is there any difference between `rename` and `rename!` when constructing a new `DataFrame` in Julia? I believe in general when modifying an existing `DataFrame` `rename!` is ideal since it modifies its arguments without generating a new object in memory.

But since no object exists in memory yet `rename` seems appropriate.

```
using DataFrames
df1 = rename( DataFrame(rand((100,2))), [:x1, :x2], [:x, :y])
df2 = rename!(DataFrame(rand((100,2))), [:x1, :x2], [:x, :y])

# Ideal formulation not using rename (currently no matching method)
df0 = DataFrame(rand((100,2)), [:x, :y])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rename!` form modifies the argument data frame whereas the `rename` version constructs a new data frame with new column names. Since you're constructing the data frame and then immediately renaming its columns, it's safe and more efficient to use `rename!`. If a reference to the inner data frame exists which you don't want to modify in a visible way, then you would want to use the non-mutating `rename` function. The difference can be seen here:

```
julia> df0 = DataFrame(rand((3,2)))
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1       │ x2       │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.625971 │ 0.401812 │
│ 2   │ 0.316224 │ 0.208431 │
│ 3   │ 0.331206 │ 0.466665 │

julia> df1 = rename(df0, [:x1, :x2], [:x, :y])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y        │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.625971 │ 0.401812 │
│ 2   │ 0.316224 │ 0.208431 │
│ 3   │ 0.331206 │ 0.466665 │

julia> df0
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1       │ x2       │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.625971 │ 0.401812 │
│ 2   │ 0.316224 │ 0.208431 │
│ 3   │ 0.331206 │ 0.466665 │

julia> df0 === df1
false

julia> df2 = rename!(df0, [:x1, :x2], [:x, :y])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y        │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.625971 │ 0.401812 │
│ 2   │ 0.316224 │ 0.208431 │
│ 3   │ 0.331206 │ 0.466665 │

julia> df0
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y        │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.625971 │ 0.401812 │
│ 2   │ 0.316224 │ 0.208431 │
│ 3   │ 0.331206 │ 0.466665 │

julia> df0 === df2
true
```

The data frame returned by `rename` is a new data frame with different column labels – i.e. `df1 !== df0` – whereas the data frame returned by `rename!` is the same data frame passed in with modified column name – i.e. `df1 === df0`. You might want to start a discussion on [Julia's Discourse forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/data) about convenience methods for constructing data frames.

Comment: is this also known as  "in place" or do I have my concepts mixed up?